# Firefox Spanish Translations

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

When I hover over a word, Firefox (3.5.5 although I think it started with 3.5.4) has taken to putting up a tooltip with the Spanish translation of the word e.g.

[image: Screenshot of Firefox with Spanish tooltip.]

I'm *reasonably* sure I didn't ask for this or install an add-on that does it. Can anyone suggest:

- where this is coming from.
- how I turn it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the [google toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Endo999/GoogleTrans)

> Like the Google toolbar: whenever you place the cursor over a word and press the SHIFT key, a popup will happen with the foreign language translation of the word. When you move the cursor away from the word, the popup window will disappear. You can do this for selected text also ( up to 500 characters) in most browsers except Safari v3- (Safari v4 is okay) and Opera.

Comment: Well that was odd. My Google toolbar had the translation option switched off, but when I switched it on to check it was indeed set to Spanish. Switching it off again and saving plus a restart of FF fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Any time Dude, exact same thing happened to me